# I'm looking for a cross-platform Python library that can play MP3 and OGG and support ALSA or similar

Tags: python, audio, cross-platform, alsa

There are several different audio libraries, however, none of them meet my exact needs:

- It needs to be cross-platform.

- It needs to be able to use the ALSA, PulseAudio or any other common default mixer under Linux.

- It needs to be able to autodetect the sample frequency.

- It needs to be (fairly) simple in usage, if instead someone can give me an extra script that will MAKE it easier for me that's accepted too.

- The only functionality I need is play/pause, seeking is a nice bonus.

- It needs to be able to play MP3 and OGG. No other formats are important to me.


The libraries I've tried so far:

PyGame - doesn't support detecting the song's frequency

PyAudiere - promising, but only loads OSS in Linux, with which I have serious mixing problems

Built-in modules - don't support MP3 and OGG as far as I'm aware

PyMedia - promising, but complicated. Also couldn't find out what mixing devices it uses.

PySonic - relies on a closed-source library.

PyQt4.phonon - promising, but wouldn't play anything. Got the following error:

> gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion `gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gstreamer.

---

> - It needs to be cross-platform.
> - It needs to be able to use the ALSA, PulseAudio or any other common default mixer under Linux.

Check - From gstreamer website:

> GStreamer has been ported to a wide
>   range of operating systems, processors
>   and compilers. This include but are
>   not limited to Linux on i86,PPC, ARM
>   using GCC. Solaris on x86 and SPARC
>   using both GCC and Forte, MacOSX,
>   Microsoft Windows using MS Visual
>   Developer and IBM OS/400.
>
> GStreamer can bridge to other
>   multimedia frameworks in order to
>   reuse existing components (e.g.
>   codecs) and use platform input/output
>   mechanisms:
>
> - Linux/Unix: OpenMAX-IL (via gst-openmax)
> - Windows: DirectShow
> - MacOS X: QuickTime

---

> - It needs to be able to autodetect the sample frequency.

Okay.

> - It needs to be (fairly) simple in usage, if instead someone can give me an extra script that will MAKE it easier for me that's accepted too.

Gstreamer has a lot of documentation and examples, and a strong community to give you support.

> - The only functionality I need is play/pause, seeking is a nice bonus.
> - It needs to be able to play MP3 and OGG. No other formats are important to me.

Then those are overwhelmed!

[Go get yours](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html)!

Comment: PERFECT! I got audio working in mere minutes! Audio switching is also a breeze. Thanks a lot! :)

Now I wonder why gstreamer is mentioned as "platform dependent" on <a href="http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/">this page</a>...

Comment: Oops, no link tag allowed on StackOverflow apparently.

Comment: @DaVince: The information that it is platform-dependent was added in 2007-11-23 14:30:37, that is, more than 2 years ago. Maybe things changed since then.

Comment: Nazarius: Huh? http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/doku.php?id=download